# PDO statments with work sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$s = &$_SESSION;
```

I am getting the below mentioned error while using session variable in prepare statements.

// $s is a session variable

My Query is:

```
$s['sQuery'] = 'SELECT * FROM `courses` WHERE (CONVERT(`title` USING utf8) = :search 
OR CONVERT(`description` USING utf8) = :search OR CONVERT(`duration` USING utf8) = :search
OR CONVERT(`fees` USING utf8) = :search OR CONVERT(`pre_requisites` USING utf8) = :search)
LIMIT '.$s['limitInc'].', '.$s['limit'];

$s['rQuery'] = $conn->prepare($s['sQuery']);

$s['rQuery']->bindValue(':search',$s['sAll'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
// $s['All'] has post value by user

$s['rQuery']->execute();
```

I am getting this error message.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'You cannot serialize or unserialize PDOStatement instances' in [no active file]:0 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: PDOStatement->__sleep() #1 {main} thrown in [no active file] on line 0

Comment: any reason you want to store PDO statement in a session variable?

Comment: So what's the question? How to avoid the error? Don't do this :)

Comment: any reason you are using all these converts too?

Comment: I'm still not sure why he got 3 downvotrs (so I upped it one). `$_SESSION` seems as good a place as any (to me, but I am far from expert), to store the result of `new PDO($connectString, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD)`. Where else should he? No one actually said (sorry if I sound dumb, but I'd like to learn. Thanks for any help ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that - for whatever reason - you are trying to store a `PDOStatement` object in the `$_SESSION` array. Unless you have specified a custom save handler objects which are stored in the session will been serialized on session save and unserialized on session load. So objects which are stored in the session must implement the `Serializable` interface, which `PDOStatement` does not.

Rather than just not implementing the serializable interface, `PDOStatement` has implemented the `__sleep()` method, which is called on serialization by the PHP engine, and throw an Exception out of it. (This is the error you are seeing). Meaning of this is just to tell you *Don't do that* ;)

Comment: It actually implements it but throws an exception when invoked :)

Comment: @Jack Indeed? Where did you get this information from? PHP doc says nothing about that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php

Comment: Well, it implements __sleep(), not exactly Serializable perhaps but similar in any case.

Comment: @Jack Now I understand what you mean: 'Although it doesn't implement Serializable it has a method __sleep() which (just) triggers the above seen PDOException'. Have updated my answer. However I expected the PHP engine to check for `Serializable` interface of object types instead of just trying to call `__sleep()`.....

Comment: It probably does look for Serializable first, but in case it's not found it will default to the older way :)